# input submit with two types of value

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, input, submit

Can you have a different value attached to a submit input than the name it shows.

something like, this is just a test, doesn't actually work:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Value to show as button text" value="value to use" />
```

The format I'm using is cshtml.

Edit:
What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a generated list of objects which each have a button to return a Request["btn"], or similar, to use in C#.
All buttons need the same name, but have to parse the id of the object to the request.

Some code:

```
@{
    if(Request["btn"] == "Value to show as button text")
    (
        int id = // submit object id
}

<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Send request" value="id1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Send request" value="id3" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Send request" value="id2" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use `data-` attributes? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use custom HTML 5 `data-*` attributes: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes, e.g. `data-val1`, `data-val2`, etc. Attributes should have unique names. You can also properly parse attribute value with some data delimiter inside it.

Comment: Hi Michael, I think you need to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve. What is your final objective? Otherwise there are many ways to "skin this cat".

Comment: Elaborated the question ^^

Answer (score 3):

change

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Value to show as button text" value="value to use" />
```

to

```
<input id='InputVal' type="submit" name="btn" value="Value to show as button text" data-value="value to use" />
```

and take the value as

```
var InputValue=$('#InputVal').attr('data-value');
```

Comment: I guess this is JQuery or JavaScript. How would it look if I were to create a Request["btn"] for the id of this in the C# part of my page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the `<button>` tag:

```
<button type="submit" value="value-to-submit">Button Text</button>
```

Comment: I've been checking around. How would a Request[] for this look like?

Answer (score 0):

you code already show "Value to show as button text" on the button to user, and value that will be passed will be "value to use"..